# NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined when compile with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, caffe

I am trying to compiled caffe with python3. After the compilation when I am trying to import caffe I am getting follwing error

```
In [1]: import caffe
Failed to include caffe_pb2, things might go wrong!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1cca3aa1f8c5> in <module>()
----> 1 import caffe

/library_install_dir/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
      2 from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver, layer_type_list
----> 3 from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
      4 from .classifier import Classifier
      5 from .detector import Detector

/library_install_dir/caffe/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py in <module>()
    975       name='type', full_name='caffe.FillerParameter.type', index=0,
    976       number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
--> 977       has_default_value=True, default_value=unicode("constant", "utf-8"),
    978       message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
    979       is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

- The issue is Python 3 renamed the unicode type to str, the old str type has been replaced by bytes.

I tried to modify the proto/caffe_pb2 but it is not working.

Anyone having similar issue with caffe. I have a working caffe with python3 support in my bare metal Now I am trying to dockerize it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the project claim Python 3 compatibility? If not, and you don't have much experience with Python, I would not set about making it so.

Comment: Ah, that file is auto-generated by Google Protocol buffers, and [that project isn't quite Python 3 ready yet](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/7).

Comment: Also see this caffe issue: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2464

Comment: thanks. I think the main issue is google_protobuf support for python3. thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `unicode` is for Python2. After `make pycaffe` command you can check `/opt/caffe-1.0/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py` file and if there is any `unicode` in the file the problem still exists. You can delete `caffe_pb2.py` and run `make pycaffe` again.

The solution is installing appropriate versions of `protoc` and `protobuf`.

**A) install protoc >= 2.6.1**

(protoc == 2.5.0 not working)

https://cuongba.com/protocol-buffers-and-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-14-04-part-1

```
wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz
cd protobuf-2.6.1
sudo ./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
protoc --version
```

**B) install protobuf>=3.4.0**

```
pip3 install protobuf>=3.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, Str is Unicode by default, 
so, in the line 977, please replace unicode function with str function

```
--> 977       has_default_value=True, default_value=Str("constant", "utf-8"),  ## Replace with Str
```

Hope this helps!!